# Maximum weighted path between two vertices in a directed acyclic Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, directed-acyclic-graphs

Love some guidance on this problem:

G is a directed acyclic graph. You want to move from vertex c to vertex z. Some edges reduce your profit and some increase your profit. How do you get from c to z while maximizing your profit. What is the time complexity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has an optimal substructure. To find the longest path from vertex `c` to vertex `z`, we first need to find the longest path from `c` to all the predecessors of `z`. Each problem of these is another smaller subproblem (longest path from `c` to a specific predecessor).

Lets denote the predecessors of `z` as `u1,u2,...,uk` and `dist[z]` to be the longest path from `c` to `z` then `dist[z]=max(dist[ui]+w(ui,z))`..

Here is an illustration with 3 predecessors omitting the edge set weights:

[image]

So to find the longest path to `z` we first need to find the longest path to its predecessors and take the maximum over (their values plus their edges weights to `z`).

This requires whenever we visit a vertex `u`, all of `u`'s predecessors must have been analyzed and computed.

So the question is: for any vertex `u`, how to make sure that once we set `dist[u]`,  `dist[u]` will never be changed later on? Put it in another way: how to make sure that we have considered all paths from `c` to `u` before considering any edge originating at `u`?

Since the graph is acyclic, we can guarantee this condition by finding a topological sort over the graph. topological sort is like a chain of vertices where all edges point left to right. So if we are at vertex `vi` then we have considered all paths leading to `vi` and have the final value of `dist[vi]`.

The time complexity: topological sort takes `O(V+E)`. In the worst case where `z` is a leaf and all other vertices point to it, we will visit all the graph edges which gives `O(V+E)`.

Answer (score 0):

Let *f(u)* be the maximum profit you can get going from *c* to *u* in your DAG. Then you want to compute *f(z)*. This can be easily computed in linear time using dynamic programming/topological sorting.

Initialize *f(u) =* -infinity for every *u* other than *c*, and *f(c) = 0*. Then, proceed computing the values of *f* in some topological order of your DAG. Thus, as the order is topological, for every incoming edge of the node being computed, the other endpoints are calculated, so just pick the maximum possible value for this node, i.e. *f(u) =* max(*f(v) + cost(v, u)*) for each incoming edge *(v, u)*.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use [Topological Sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) instead of [Bellman Ford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) since its DAG.

Source:- http://www.utdallas.edu/~sizheng/CS4349.d/l-notes.d/L17.pdf

**EDIT:-**

G is a DAG with negative edges.

> Some edges reduce your profit and some increase your profit

- Edges - increase profit - positive value
- Edges - decrease profit -
  negative value

After TS, for each vertex U in TS order - relax each outgoing edge.

```
dist[] = {-INF, -INF, ….}
dist[c] = 0 // source

for every vertex u in topological order
  if (u == z) break; // dest vertex
  for every adjacent vertex v of u
    if (dist[v] < (dist[u] + weight(u, v))) // < for longest path = max profit
      dist[v] = dist[u] + weight(u, v)

ans = dist[z];
```

Comment: After you do the Topological sort, what algorithm gives you the maximum value path?

Comment: This is correct only when you are looking for SHORTEST paths.

Comment: @Xline agreed, you need to compute the longest path... see my updated answer

Comment: @MiteshPathak also I'm not looking for longest path from to any node, but between two specific nodes

Comment: @evenodd In that case, break before the `for` loop when `(v == dest node)`

Comment: @evenodd updated my answer. It should be u == dest node

Comment: The problem is that if the breaks when it reaches dest node, it may not have explored other paths to that dest noide

Comment: @evenodd that's the beauty of TS -> if u reach dest path all the vertex will be in forward direction. So all  node after dest won't point back to dest.

Comment: @MiteshPathak Yeah but it's possible two have two different paths to dest node, right?

Comment: @evenodd Yep. But all paths will have nodes that are before dest in TS order. No path exist from nodes after dest - since there is no back edge in TS. Try with an example and u'll get what I'm saying :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65106/discussion-between-evenodd-and-mitesh-pathak).